# weblogic 10 TimerManager avoiding propagation of security context to the scheduled tasks

Tags: weblogic, commonj

We are using weblogic 10 and I am using the commonj's TimerManager which is part of weblogic to schedule a task, everything is fine but I have one problem. The securitycontext of the thread which scheduled the TimerListener task is somehow stored in the TimerListener task and is being used for the work done in the TimeListener task and this is causing the problem for me. Can anyone of you pls point me on how to avoid propagation of security context to the scheduled tasks from the thread which scheduled those tasks?

Answer (score 0):

This is way late but anyway, one way to avoid propagating context is to use unmanaged threads i.e. spawn threads without commonj. Of this throws the baby out with the bathwater.